# potential bottlenecks in java concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency

I worked on implementing a reasoner, a complex stuff. I tried to improve performance by employing parallelized threads, but only gained overhead.

My question is whether there are other potential bottlenecks besides **monitors** (**locks**). I removed all such indicators as `synchronized` and `volatile` from my program.

I use `java.util.concurrent` utilities, and split data into standalone arrays for threads.

Comment: Did you test on a multi-core machine?

Comment: Did you monitor your application with VisualVm to analyze the source of your overhead?

Comment: @paislee: Yes, I run it on an eight-core computer, and normally generate **at most** 10 threads.

Comment: Hi all, can `static` without `synchronized` members result in bottlenecks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most useful think you can do is ensure you thread are performing long sequences of independent work.  These sequences need to be significantly longer than the overhead you are likely to incur (say 1 - 10 micro-seconds)

A common mistake is to break up the work too finely (creating a lot of overhead in the process).  You only need one task per core to keep every core busy.

Without most details of what you are trying to do and how you are breaking up your work, its hard to suggest anything more specific.

Comment: Hi @Peter Lawrey, thanks for the suggestion. I had achieved a speedup at most 3, but after I have added some optimization techniques, the single worker's performance improves a lot while the speedup disappears. I guess that is what you say. Do you know whether `static`, without `synchronized`, members can result in bottlenecks?

Comment: Bottlenecks occur in concurrent when attempting to modify a share resource.  You can read a shared resource without bottle neck problems. (Reading/writing thread local resources isn't a problem either)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will do a check.

Answer (score 2):

- A potential bottleneck is the creation of new threads. If this happens a lot you should consider using a thread-pool.
- Another bottleneck might be allocation of arrays in often called methods.

You could run your application with [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) to detect the actual bottlenecks. JProfiler will instrument your byte-code at load-time and offers you a deep look inside your application concerning memory consumption, runtime performance, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [Disruptor](http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/), even if only to read their Technical Paper, which goes in depth on the subject.